# how to change label text on click on segmentControl in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using segmentedControl in iphone application i want that when

with YES and NO

I have also one lable i want that when YES is selected lable should display YES other wise

but its not changing with my code

```
  -(IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged{

   switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.segmentLabel.text =@"YES";
        break;
    case 1:
        self.segmentLabel.text =@"NO";
        break;

    default:
        break;

}


   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple use 
    setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:

So the code should looks like

```
NSString *str;
switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
case 0: {
    str = @"YES";
    break;
}
case 1: {
    str = @"NO";
    break;
}
default:
    break;

[self.segmentedControll setTitle:str forSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
```

or simpler version

```
if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [self.segmentedControll setTitle:@"YES" forSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [self.segmentedControll setTitle:@"NO" forSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
```

Comment: where to use this code in same code mine i have written in that but nothing works

Comment: Nothing works is a vague statement. Was `segmentedControlIndexChanged` invoked? Is self.segmentedControll not nil? Did you connect all elements through IB?

Comment: Did you add action for segmentedControl?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Look at the image and as per that do proper wiring (select Value changed option).

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{

if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [self.segmentedControll setTitle:@"YES" forSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [self.segmentedControll setTitle:@"NO" forSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
}

}
```